# Receive error "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'" when update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am building an API. But I receive the following error.

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

My request is a HTTP PUT and I'm trying to update my database. I have searched for many days but I can't find an answer. Below is my request code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
 [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkGRI.png)

Code in Controller

```
    [HttpPut]
    public void CGNATObjUpdate(int ID)
    {
        Library.Instances.Value.CGNATObjUpdate(ID);

    }
```

Comment: The browser will perform a GET by default, which the API does not currently support (based on your code) use the developer tools in the browser (if supported) to construct a PUT request or use an external tool like Postman or Fiddler to construct valid requests to the API

Answer (score 0):

You need to send PUT request aswell. [HttpPut] Allows your method to be triggered for PutRequests only, but in your example you just put link into browser and this simple GET request. Try to use something like Postman to send correct request.

Another way is to check that your controller alows to trigger action by name, for this you need to configure routing for your controller. Just set

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class CGNATUpdateApiController : Controller
    {

    }
```

Now you can call Action by name, otherwise you will not be able to call Controller action by it`s name, and you need to call Controller:

> /api/CGNATUpdateApi?ID=3

just with correct method (PUT) and it will call first PUT method in controller.

Comment: First, thank you for your Reply. I tried to  use  PostMan and  this is error: 
"could not get any response"

Comment: Check the Routing then... also please give the full class for future problem solving